# Post contact form to html document

Tags: php

I currently have a contact page that emails me when it gets submitted. I want to send the fields to another htm page on the server instead so staff can access the information by viewing the page in their browser. So even if they don't have access to email, they can view the page from their browser.

The information sent must accumulate on the form, ie new submissions must submit to the ame form without deleting previous submissions.

Do I amend the code? Do I make a few changes like changing the 'mymail' to 'myform = "form.htm" ' I made a few changes and tried submitting but have no idea how to make the form work.

Below is the code that sends the email.

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "mail@abc.co.za";
$subject = "Contact Form";


/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name     = check_input($_POST['name']);
$contactnr  = check_input($_POST['contactnr']);
$email        = check_input($_POST['email']);
$phoneoremail        = check_input($_POST['phoneoremail']);
$message        = check_input($_POST['message']);
$ipaddress        =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$iphost        =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];


 /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
 if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
 {
 show_error("E-mail address not valid");
 }

 /* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
 if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
 {
   $website = '';
}

/* Prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Contact form has been submitted

Details:

Name: $name
Phone Number: $contactnr
E-mail: $email
Message: $message
Sender IP Address: $ipaddress
Form submitted via server: $iphost




End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
 mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

 /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
 header('Location: thankyou.htm');
 exit();

 /* Functions we used */
 function check_input($data, $problem='')
  {
    $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
    show_error($problem);
     }
      return $data;
      }

     function show_error($myError)
       {
        ?>
          <html>
                <body>

              <b>Please provide missing information so we can assist you:</b><br />
              <?php echo $myError; ?>

            </body>
            </html>
          <?php
         exit();
           }
           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post this to an HTML page aswell as sending it per E-Mail, why don't you just write to an HTML file?

```
$file = 'formdata.html';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "Details:<br>
             Name: $name<br>
             Phone Number: $contactnr<br>
             E-mail: $email<br>
             Message: $message<br>
             Sender IP Address: $ipaddress<br>
             Form submitted via server: $iphost<br><hr>";
// Write the contents to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Maybe include formdata.html then as an iFrame on a page only the staff can access?

Comment: Although here if the user submits html code in for example "$message", it will be displayed as HTML code. You can also $message = str_replace("<", "", $message); and $message = str_replace("&lt;", "", $message); in order to remove possible HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code posts to the html form now, but does not include the actual fields completed on the contact form. I.e the following is posted excluding the fields I.m looking for:                                                                                    Details:
Name:
Phone Number:
E-mail:
Message:
Sender IP Address:
Form submitted via server:

Comment: My fault, added your code in wrong location :). Thank you! Yes will include the form in an iframe.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Comment: Two more questions: How would I post new info at the top of the list instead of bottom? I.e. new posts are seen immediately instead of scrolling to bottom. I have added a time stamp, but the time zone is out. How would I correct the zone with +2 hours? Or how would I get the server's time and date? That would also solve it?

Comment: Add it by using code like this:

$file = fopen("iframefile.html", "c");
fwrite($file, "Content to be added on the first line");
fclose($file);

    or turn around the code you already have by using: 

current = "Details: <br>Name: $name";
current .= file_get_contents($file);

file_put_contents($file, $current);

Comment: Also, to add two hours to your time use:
$time = date('h:i:s', time()+7200);